# Filtering by just time in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm attempting to create a filter on the view that allows users to filter the data by time ranges:

[image]

When users select this, it maps to an enum type `TimeRange` that contains two date objects. These date objects contain just the respective times, called `lowerBound` and `upperBound` respectively. For example:

```
MIDNIGHT_TO_SIX(1, Date.parse("HH:mm:ss", "00:00:00"), Date.parse("HH:mm:ss", "06:00:00")
```

This makes a `Date` object. Because I have not specified the date portion, that is set to epoch date. When I use these in a critieria for filtering:

```
and {
   or {
       eq('startDateTime', range.lowerBound)
       gt('startDateTime', range.lowerBound)
   }

   or {
       eq('startDateTime', range.upperBound)
       lt('startDateTime', range.upperBound)
   }
}
```

Nothing is being returned! This is clearly because none of the dates in my database are before or equal to epoch time, as per the last `or` closure.

Is there a way of telling the criteria to only use the time portion during the comparison, or is there a way that I can declare `lowerBound` and `upperBound` to not be concerned with the `Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the straight-forward approach would be to save the number of seconds (or millis) from 00:00:00, so that the lookup is as easy as:

```
enum Range { 
  MIDNIGHT_TO_SIX( 1, 0, 6 * 60 * 60 ) //in seconds 
}
```

criteria:

```
{
  between 'startInSec', range.lower, range.upper 
}
```

Comment: Independently I did something nearly identical to this, and I've got it working. Good suggestion! +1